# Arms inner part of the elbow is deformed in a circular pattern instead of a crease

Tags: mesh, bones, weight-painting

Basically, the elbow does not bend in its correct way. Instead, I'm getting this:

[image]

Note the subdivision surface value is set to 2. At subdivision level 0, I get a better (not perfect) result:

[image]

I can't tell if this is because of the positions of the loop cuts or the weight paint: 
[image]

I used Rigify to create this but wasn't sure if this is normal and I have to go edit every bone in weight paint mode. Is there a quicker or easier way to fix this?

(It's also easy for me to roll back and change the position of the bones and regenerating the mesh if needed)

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your character in *Object* mode and in the *Properties* panel > *Modifiers*, put the *Armature* modifier above the *Subsurf* modifier, it should fix the problem.